Using popup event for 3rd tab issue
Using Playwright, I have this test which does the following:

go to site to login - redirects to okta - then redirects back to site (first website)
Then I click on a option on the website which opens a new tab (a second tab).
From the second tab I middle mouse click on a hyper link to open a new tab (third website/third tab)

The test I have works with no issues. However, in headed mode the third tab that opens does not come in focus. It doesn't effect the test, but it would be nice if someone was viewing it for the third tab to be in foreground/brought to front/focus.
Using the popup event, it only seems to bring the second tab in focus even though the third one is opened later after the second one.
Any ideas on how to make the third tab in front/focus in headed mode? Again, it doesn't effect the test but it would be nice for viewing
Test that works but third tab not in focus:
  await page.getByLabel('Email').fill(EMAIL);
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Next' }).click();

  await page.getByLabel('Password').fill(PASSWORD);
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign In' }).click();

  // first tab/page
  await page.waitForURL('https://first-website.com');

  await page.locator('#main-menu-nav-agency-links').click();

  // second tab
  const page2Promise = page.waitForEvent('popup');
  await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Configuration' }).click();
  const page2 = await page2Promise;

  await page2.getByRole('link', { name: 'app foo hyperlink' }).click({
    button: 'middle'
  });


  const pages = page.context().pages();

  // third tab at pages[2]
  const logOutMsg = pages[2].getByRole('heading', { name: 'foobar' });

  await expect(logOutMsg).toBeVisible();

What I tried but did not work:
  await page.getByLabel('Email').fill(EMAIL);
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Next' }).click();

  await page.getByLabel('Password').fill(PASSWORD);
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign In' }).click();

  // first tab/page
  await page.waitForURL('https://first-website.com');

  await page.locator('#main-menu-nav-agency-links').click();

  // second tab
  const page2Promise = page.waitForEvent('popup');
  await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Configuration' }).click();
  const page2 = await page2Promise;

  // third tab
  const page3Promise = page2.waitForEvent('popup'); // even though tab opens here the event never gets caught
  await page2.getByRole('link', { name: 'app foo hyperlink' }).click({ button: 'middle' })
  const page3 = await page3Promise;

  const logOutMsg = page3.getByRole('heading', { name: 'foobar' });
  await expect(logOutMsg).toBeVisible();                                                                                                                                       

                                                                                                                                       


Without https://first-website.com it's rather difficult to help. Can you share a complete, runnable [mcve]? Thanks.
